# AMD(approximate minimum degree) algorithm in R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

In matlab P = amd(A) returns the approximate minimum degree permutation vector for the sparse matrix A, in R does we have the same command?

Comment: There is `colamdR` in the `Datasmith` package

Comment: mt<-matrix(c(4,rep(1,5),0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1),4,4),in R: colamdR(mt) return [1] 1 2 3 4; in Matlab amd(mt) return [1] 4,3,2,1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the chol function in the Matrix package... not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but it's from the documentation for that package (" Returns (and stores) the Cholesky decomposition of x. If pivot is true, the Approximate Minimal Degree (AMD) algorithm is used to create a reordering of the rows and columns of x so as to reduce fill-in.")

```
> library(Matrix)
> M2 <- toeplitz(as(c(1,.5, rep(0,12), -.1), "sparseVector"))
> C2 <- chol(M2, pivot=TRUE)
> C2
15 x 15 sparse Matrix of class "dtCMatrix"


 [1,] 1 0.5000000 .         .         .         .         .         .         .        
 [2,] . 0.8660254 0.5773503 .         .         .         .         .         .        
 [3,] . .         0.8164966 0.6123724 .         .         .         .         .        
 [4,] . .         .         0.7905694 0.6324555 .         .         .         .        
 [5,] . .         .         .         0.7745967 0.6454972 .         .         .        
 [6,] . .         .         .         .         0.7637626 0.6546537 .         .
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1esm3vz8jtu9SqMJIJdM0wn6_nMz_v2wJ?usp=sharing,the link show what I want do.Since I want make the Cholesky decomposition  sparse,but use chol(M2, pivot=TRUE),didn't make the sense.